# SQL Casting with Decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

Lets say I get 8048 seconds for my SQL code:

```
SUM(DATEDIFF(s, '8/25/2015', '8/26/2015')) as 'Seconds'
```

How can I get the same answer for Minutes and hours... but have them be a decimal? This is for hours:

```
 Cast(((SUM(DATEDIFF(s, '8/25/2015', '8/26/2015'))/60.00)/60.00) as decimal(8,2)) as 'Hours'
```

But I keep getting 2.00 hours.... when it should be 2.34 hours?

Comment: Datediff of dates you've specified is 24 hours exactly (1 day). So why do you want it to be 2.34 hours? Probably sample in your question is incorrect.

Comment: Your sample results are incorrect: the first one returns `86400` seconds. The second one returns `24.00` not `2.00` hours.

Comment: I understand that it is 1day.. I was saying for example... If it was 8048 seconds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try relocating the `CAST` statement to inside of the `SUM()`:

```
CAST((SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(s, [date1], [date2]) AS Decimal(20,2))/60.00)/60.00)) AS Decimal(20,2)) as 'Hours'
```

The way you have it set up now, the value is probably rounded before you even cast it

Answer (score 1):

DATEDIFF returns an interval.   CAST it as a float or decimal to get a decimal result from your math formula:

```
 Cast(((SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(s, '8/25/2015', '8/26/2015') AS decimal(8,2))/60.00)/60.00) as decimal(8,2)) as 'Hours'
```